# WordPress website redirects to install.php page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a beginner in WordPress. Sorry if I am technically incorrect.

WordPress website redirects to the `install.php` page once every few hours and keeps redirecting for an hour or so. It automatically fixes itself, with no problem for a few hours and the same thing happens again. I talked to my hosting provider (LWS) and they said it could be due to MySQL database quota problem but I checked and found that I get very few visitors to my website.

Here is the error log [IP and website name redacted]:

```
[Sun Jan 24 10:08:01.420576 2021] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 32498:tid 
140692919674624] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:33474] AH01071: Got error 'PHP 
message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_set_charset(): Error executing query in 
/htdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 792', referer: https://sitename.com/
```

I searched for guides on Google and YouTube but most of them were about confirming and correcting the table prefix name. In my case, the table prefix was already correct.

Here is what the line 792 of `wp-db.php` says:

```
[790]if ( $this->use_mysqli ) {
[791]               if ( function_exists( 'mysqli_set_charset' ) && 
$this->has_cap( 'set_charset' ) ) {
[792]                   $set_charset_succeeded = mysqli_set_charset( 
$dbh, $charset );
[794]               }
```

Kindly suggest possible solutions to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggested actions you could take:

- Check that your hosting provider has available disk space for your
  database.
- Check that your .htaccess is correct and not writable by
  the webserver.
- Virus scan your install of wordpress.
- Check if you have any crons running that may cause problems.
- Test the site on localhost or another host to see if the problem persists.